# enter Missing identity check when audit code

Tags: java

I was writing code and using codepro tool for auditing, while I was writing a equals method, I encountered this kind of audit Missing identity check, I dont know how to correct it

my method code:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    boolean result = false;
    if(o instanceof Coordinate){
        if(((Coordinate) o).x == x &&
                ((Coordinate) o).y == y){
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The description of the audit is this:

Description :Missing identity check

Explanation:
The equals method should compare the identity of the receiver and the argument, returning true if they are the same.

Recommendation: 1. Add a test for object identity.

I dont know what means test for object identity, should I use unit test or something? Thank you for anyone helps me.

Comment: I think what it means is that you should first check `if ( this == o )  return true` as a short circuit for equality.

Comment: You might be interested in reading this http://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/1317692

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I am reading the material you provided, thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

it simply means you should check if the two objects are the same

```
  this == o;
```